# Expanding width of centerColor gradient in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following that currently works fine

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="#5790A6"
            android:endColor="#DC3626" android:angle="180"
            android:centerColor="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

It creates a rectangle with 3 color gradient. However I am trying to expand the width of the black center gradient so that the start and end color only take 5% each.

From left to right. 5% red, 90% black, 5% blue.

The use of centerX only looks to move the center color, expanding the start/end color.

Is there any way of doing this?